# Bootstrap css fixed header no space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I have a page (Number 2 on image).
I want to fixing the header, but the container was under the header.
I dont understand why.

The Number 1 image is an example code. There is good.

Whats wrong?
I hope someone can help me! Thanks
(Laravel 5)

[image]

Example: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/#
My page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://test.dev">
                    Laravel
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://test.dev/home">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                                            <li><a href="http://test.dev/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://test.dev/register">Register</a></li>
                                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    Your Application's Landing Page.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this solution wil be helpfull 
[JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oczsxnc4/6/)

UPDATE:
Smarties way will be to add new class with row div so your bootstrap css stay untouched.

```
.row-withmargin{
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Body padding required](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)**

The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. **Tip**: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

In the example link you provided, the image 1, it has a container called `jumbotron` which has `padding 60px;` that is the reason the contents are not hidden under the navbar

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oczsxnc4/7/)**

Answer (score 3):

According to **[bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)** The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add `padding` to the top of the `<body>`.

**CSS:**

```
body{
padding:70px;
}
```

or

Place your content in the **jumbotron container** like in the image1 and remove the `background-color` of the jumbotron with your own `css`